# pandas dataframe identify parts of column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I know how to filter cols in Pandas. However now my data looks like this that i have a col with lots of 0 and then a 1 when a marker is set by the data generating programme (which i can't modify) and so on. However afterward the marker 1 it returns to 0,0,... until the marker 2 is set.

What I want to do is this:

(1) search for the next marker (e.g "2")

(2) fill all 0 cols between 1 and 2 with "1" and so on (my data goes up to marker 98)

Is there a way to achieve this via a loop function?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample code or data? See MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ##Create a list from marker colum integers > 0 to use for looking: 
markers = df['marker'].tolist()
markers[:] = (value for value in markers if value != 0) # removes 0

# Look for markers in whole df["marker"] column and replace 0 between e.g. 1 and 2 with 1 etc.

Comment: I didn't get very far from yesterday and I am new here so I'm not so skilled yet with posting code...

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide your data, your code so far, and the result you are getting?

Comment: Dear Evan, I solved the problem by now . Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You can post your own solution and mark it as accepted!